# when dataType in ajax must be json

Tags: php, json, ajax

in php
 i found data is wrong from ajax response but when using **dataType** **json** it be correct
 so i don't know when making **dataType** is **json** in ajax and how to make it default 'html'

Comment: please show the relevant code you have and _where_ exactly you get _what_ wrong "response".

Comment: the code was from long time but the question in public when using json in dataType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer your question.
You have to use `dataType:html` when you want to return HTML as plain text.
If you use `dataType:json`, the ajax call will return your data as JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) Object format `{key1 : 'value1', key2 : 'value2', key3 : 'value3',..., key_n : value_n}`. If you want to return your data as JSON object, you need to provide key and value and finally you need to encode as JSON object before you return it. You nedd to provide dataType in every ajax call. If you don't provide dataType value, the Ajax Intelligent System will consider in this order `(xml, json, script, or html)`. For more details, visit jQuery Ajax official website [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).